# What is a good daily newsletter?

Tags: quantitative, news

What newsletters do you read daily that help you learn new methods, keep up to date on news, new research, etc in quant finance? Looking for something similar to those morning newsletters sent out by The Economist, Reuters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantocracy](https://quantocracy.com/) provides a good collection of quant related resources as well as a list of top ranked blogs. You can subscribe to its daily summary via RSS or email.

[ML-Quant](https://www.ml-quant.com/) provides monthly newsletters and daily streams of trending papers, seminars, news and blogs, also including videos and podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenQuant](https://openquant.substack.com/) is a good mix of news headlines, articles, resources, and career opportunities.